# How to broadcast datas on a meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

first, I would like to apologize for my bad English, I hope you'll understand me!

So, I am making a video game (very original!) for a uni project. It is an online multiplayer game. I am using Meteor and Phaser. 
It is basically a game in which you control a boat and you need to shoot on other players' boats.

My problem is that the other players positions doesn't update in real time on the client machine. Actually, the is a latency between 5 and 10 secondes (maybe more, I didn't timed it).
I think this is due to the way I update the position of other players. In my phaser main update loop, I update the database with the new position of the boat. I think the update function is called 60 times per second, it is quite a lot! I don't know if Meteor can handle so much updates in such a short time?
So this is how I update the database, then I need to update the other players position on the user machine.

For that, I have a subscription to the Boats collection, and I have an observeChanges function that update the position of the other players each time the database is changed.

I guess this is not the easiest way to do it, and not the most efficient!
My first idea was to use something like Meteor streams or Streamy, so that each user could broadcast constantly his position. But I read that Meteor streams is no longer updated, and I couldn't make Streamy work.

So my question is: what do you recommend to broadcast very (very) often datas to other users?
If I manage to do that, I think I can save boats datas in the database every 10 seconds for example.

Thank you :)

Again, I'm sorry for my english, I hope I made my problem understandable. Also, I am quite new to Meteor, so please don't judge me if I have very bad practices ^^

Comment: I have it on github here : https://github.com/manucoffin/bandofpirates.git
it is in client/client.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. The simplest may be running MongoDB completely in memory: http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis

Another option is to just use real Redis with Meteor. It would require running a Redis server of course. The learning curve on that may be higher than the option above.
https://github.com/meteor/redis-livedata

Finally, Meteor Streams looks like it would work though it looks like it would mean major changes to the structure of your game. http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/

Comment: If you stay with MongoDB on this app you may want to look into Kadira and the BulletProof Meteor course. They teach a lot about performance profiling and have a freemium service that can help you with it. Food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for these resources, I started to read them, it seems really interesting! Actually, I found a way to use Streamy (similar to meteor-streams), I find it easier for my project and it does not requires that much changes ^^